# Why hhvm performance is terrible on small webapp?

Tags: php, yii, performance-testing, hhvm

Recently i made a performance scenarios with hhvm and i found hhvm faster than php-fpm5.5 (with opcache) only if the testing website quite big (200+ includes) but perform terrible with small footprint application like Yii 1.1.16 testdrive contact page.

did i make some mistake or it is normal?

environment:

```
Machine: 64 GB / 20 CPUs digitalocean
PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.7 OPcache v7.0.3
HipHop VM 3.6.1 (rel)
Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-46-generic x86_64)
```

[image: server: 64 GB / 20 CPUs (digitalocean); apache benchmark on /testdrive/index.php?r=site/contact]

cpu consumption serving small footprint webpages on hhvm
[image: cpu consumption serving small footprint webpages on hhvm]

Answer (score 0):

HHVM can be slower for /very/ lightweight pages; however, there's not enough information here to be sure if that's the case here:

- are you sending warmup requests? If so, how many, and how? The JIT will be slower for the first few requests on almost any workload (same applies to other JITs, such as the JVM)

  - how are you actually measuring? Siege, ab, ?

Comment: hi @FredEmmott, i used apache benchmark. the benchmark run more than a minute so i think it is enough time to warm up. and the processing time did not decreased during the test.